# Is there a point-free way to convert a conditional check into a Maybe type of the input?

Tags: haskell, pointfree, option-type

I am just working through some simple exercises in haskell and was wondering if there was a point-free way of converting an if-then-else statement into a `Maybe` type: `Nothing` being returned if the condition is false, and `Just` the input if the condition is true.

In short, given some:

```
maybeIf :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
maybeIf cond a = if cond a then Just a else Nothing
```

Is there an implementation that is point-free with respect to `a`? I've also been looking at a more concrete version, `a -> Maybe a`, and feel like there may be an answer somewhere in `Control.Arrow`. However, since `Maybe` is a data type and if-else statements control data flow, I'm unsure if there is a clean way of doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import `find` from `Data.Foldable` and then it's quite simply:

```
import Data.Foldable(find)

maybeIf cond = find cond . Just
```

The function `find` is not complicated so you could quite easily define it yourself less generically, in terms of `Maybe`, but it isn't actually so different from your own implementation of `maybeIf` so you might not gain much, depending on why you wanted to do it.

Answer (score 8):

The main thing getting in the way of making that pointfree is the `if`/`then`/`else`. You can define an `if'` combinator, or you can use this generalized version that I define and use often:

```
ensure p x = x <$ guard (p x)
```

Standard tools give successive point-free versions as

```
ensure p = ap (<$) (guard . p)
ensure = ap (<$) . (guard .)
```

though I really don't think either are better than the pointful version.

Comment: `Data.Bool` has `bool`.

Comment: Very interesting! I think I like this answer the best as it has the most material to learn in a simple and concise manner. I'm going to give this to @Peter since his answer is the most readable and I guess I did only asked for point-free wrt a.

Answer (score 4):

If we choose a Church-encoding for Booleans…

```
truth :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
truth True  t f = t
truth False t f = f
```

Then we can write a point-free `maybeIf` in Applicative-style.

```
maybeIf :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
maybeIf = liftA3 truth <*> pure Just <*> pure (pure Nothing)
```

Some intuitions…

```
f <$> m₁ <*> … <*> mₙ = \x -> f (m₁ x) … (mₙ x)
liftAₙ f <$> m₁ <*> … <*> mₙ = \x -> f <$> m₁ x <*> … <*> mₙ x
```

Here is a rendering in PNG format of the above "intuitions", in case your installed fonts do not support the needed unicode characters.

[image]

So therefore:

```
liftA3 truth <*> pure Just <*> pure (pure Nothing)
= liftA3 truth <$> id <*> pure Just <*> pure (pure Nothing)
= \p -> truth <$> id p <*> (pure Just) p <*> (pure (pure Nothing)) p
= \p -> truth <$> p <*> Just <*> pure Nothing
= \p -> \a -> truth (p a) (Just a) ((pure Nothing) a)
= \p -> \a -> truth (p a) (Just a) Nothing
```

Comment: I can't see some of the characters! After "Some intuitions..." the code block subscripts(?) which are not `1` are boxed question marks.

Comment: @stites I have added a rendering which you should be able to see.

Answer (score 3):

Following [dfeuer's lead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535067/is-there-a-point-free-way-to-convert-a-conditional-check-into-a-maybe-type-of-th/34540058#comment56816052_34535374) (and using Daniel Wagner's new name for this function),

```
import Data.Bool (bool)
--         F    T    
-- bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a

ensure :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
ensure p x = bool (const Nothing) Just (p x) x

ensure p   = join (bool (const Nothing) Just . p)
           = bool (const Nothing) Just =<< p  

ensure     = (bool (const Nothing) Just =<<)
```

`join` is a monadic function, `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`, but for functions it is simply

```
join   k  x = k x x
(k =<< f) x = k (f x) x
```

`join` is accepted as a replacement for [W combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,_C,_K,_W_system) in point-free code.

You only wanted it point-free with respect to the value argument, but it's easy to transform the equation with `join` further (readability of the result is another issue altogether), as

```
          = join ((bool (const Nothing) Just .) p)
          = (join . (bool (const Nothing) Just .)) p
```

Indeed,

```
 #> (join . (bool (const Nothing) Just .)) even 3
Nothing

 #> (bool (const Nothing) Just =<<) even 4
Just 4
```

But I'd much rather see `\p x -> listToMaybe [x | p x]` in an actual code.

Or just `\p x -> [x | p x]`, with Monad Comprehensions. Which *is* the same as [Daniel Wagner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34535374/849891) `x <$ guard (p x)`, only with different syntax.

Comment: @dfeuer I've edited, thanks. The resulting expression is unremarkable, but at least it's pointfree now.

Comment: Hm.... I wonder if there's any sense to be found in the generalization `ensure p = join (bool (const empty) pure . p)`.

Comment: @dfeuer nice! it's much clearer that way... and with the new base this is the same as Daniel Wagner's excellent  `(<$) <*> guard . p`, since now [`guard :: Alternative f => Bool -> f ()`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard)! (i.e. not `MonadPlus`)

Comment: @dfeuer somehow I forgot about `=<<`; it's even simpler with it, `(bool (const empty) pure =<<)`.

Answer (score 1):

This function is defined in Control.Monad.Plus and is called [partial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monadplus-1.4.2/docs/Control-Monad-Plus.html)