# How to implement f (g x) (h x) point-freely in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279306/what-does-f-g-mean-in-haskell/20279307#20279307) one learns how to implement the function `\x y z -> f x (g y z)` in a pointless way in Haskell, where `f` and `g` are functions. And my question is

> How to write the function `\x -> f (g x) (h x)` in a pointfree manner in Haskell? Here `f` `g` `h` are functions for which `f (g x) (h x)` is defined.

The idea I currently have in mind is something like the following.

```
uncurry f (mapTuple ($ x) (g, h))
```

But several tries shows that this is fallacious; even the part `map ($ x) [g, h]` is suspicious: what if `g` and `h` have different ranges?

In addition, readability is not too much an issue here.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: That's just `liftA2 f g h`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I am having a headache understanding what `APPlicative` is. Maybe some other way without being `Applicative`? Thanks still. :)

Comment: Sure: `liftM2 f g h` :-)

Comment: Thanks for this nice suggestion! Indeed monads come in quite handy in such higher-order tasks. I would like to see some `built from scratch` example, if any, though. Again thanks for pointing out this use of monads. :D

Comment: Note that `Applicative` is more fundamental than the monad; technically it's actually simpler (but for some strange reason, monads seem indeed easier to understand, I also struggled with applicatives for a while). Anyway, `liftA2`/`liftM2` rely on a particular, somewhat controversial applicative _instance_ of functions, so this isn't really “a monad solution” but a solution exploiting that instance. The really fundamental approach is to use the [cartesian monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_monoidal_category) property of Haskell functions; this is what `Arrow` does.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for pointing out the interesting fact that `Arrow` uses the cartesian monoidal category property. I think I will have a long-time headache then. :-P

Comment: The process of converting a lambda term into an equivalent that instead of lambda abstraction uses a suitable set of combinators is called [abstraction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Combinatory_logic&oldid=724463160#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis). The link shows that combinators **S** and **K** are such a set, and `liftA2` or `liftM2` for the reader monad is just the **S** combinator. I wrote an article about this relationship a few years ago in [The Monad Reader #17](https://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/issue17.pdf).

Comment: @PetrPudlák `liftA2` is not **S**. `ap` is **S**.

Comment: @melpomene You're right, that was a mistake.

Comment: @melpomene I don't see why `ap` is **S**: I am told `S x y z = x z (y z)`, but IMHO, `ap` just lifts function application? Also I like this abstraction elimination: quite interesting!

Comment: According to the abstraction-elimination process in the link we can also write  -----------------------------------------

    `S (S (K f) (S (K g) I)) (S (K h) I),`

per chance?

Comment: @awllower https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7050431229399e6002dd3a56abf256a7

Comment: I see! Thanks for pointing out this detailed expansion of `ap` in the case of `(->) e` monad. So what I wrote above may be written as `ap (ap (const f) g) h` after eta reduction?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Sorry about the mention after a long time; I found that we can view arrows as strong monads in the bicategory of pro-functors, and in fact the notion of arrows is not limited to cartesian categories, but we can define it over a monodical category. BTW, I am referring to [this oar](http://www-kb.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~asada/papers/arrStrMnd.pdf). And this left me wondering if there is a more mathematical fit for applicative. :P

Comment: @awllower: well, that “monad in **Prof**” stuff is another aspect of `Arrow`, the one you get from `arr`. However, I feel `arr` is foremostly a bit of a hack to get access to the simple isomorphisms you need for a cartesian monoidal category, without needing a whole bunch of methods (`(a,b)->(b,a)` and `((a,b),c)->(a,(b,c))`, etc.). An arrow is not “defined over a cartesian category”, it **is** a CMC. — That's not to say the 2-category view as in the article you linked isn't valid – just, I don't see how this is useful, and fear it's somewhat responsible for the bad rep `Arrow` is getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) suggested, `\x -> f (g x) (h x)` is equivalent to `liftM2 f g h`.

When you have question concerning how to convert Haskell code into pointfree Haskell code, you can just try [Pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io).

It is a great tool which often can tell you when NOT to use pointfree code because it goes completely unreadable sometimes :-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this interesting website. :)

Comment: Better use `liftA2` instead of `liftM2`, the latter is kinda deprecated since the AMP.

Comment: You can also use the `pointfree` command line utility (and optionally write bindings to integrate it into ghci sessions): https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree

Comment: @BenjaminKovach I tried to `cabal install pointfree` butter some reason the package cannot be installed. It told me such modules as Plugin.Pl.Common cannot be found while those modules are in the correct position. So I guess I will make do with pointfree.io. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 6):

The [arrow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html) version would be

```
uncurry f . (g &&& h)
```

or

```
(g &&& h) >>> uncurry f
```

As a diagram:

```
        g ────
       ╱          ╲
──── &&&      >>>  uncurry f ───
       ╲          ╱
        h ────
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Now I shall try to learn some arrows as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Applicative-style

```
f <$> g <*> h
```

[Control.Compose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.9.11/docs/Control-Compose.html)

```
join ((g ~> h ~> id) f)
```

[Data.Function.Meld](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-function-meld-0.1.1.0/docs/Data-Function-Meld.html)

```
join (f $* g $$ h *$ id)
```

[Data.Function.Tacit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-function-tacit-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Function-Tacit.html)

```
lurryA @N1 (f <$> (g <$> _1) <*> (h <$> _1))
lurryA @N4 (_1 <*> (_2 <*> _4) <*> (_3 <*> _4)) f g h
```

Comment: After a long time I finally got what this code says: `f <$> g <*> h`. I think it is no other than `ap (f . g) h`. In any case, thanks for such useful information.

Comment: @awllower check out the "intuitions" I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34536499/260584 which offer a straight-forward way to think about Applicative on functions. Note also that `<$>` is `.`, `<*>` is the Lambda Calculus combinator S, and `pure` is the combinator K (which is `const`).

Answer (score 0):

This only serves to collect and put into order the answers in the comments.
According to the abstraction-elimination process in the link in the comment by @ PetrPudlák, we can also write

```
S (S (K f) (S (K g) I)) (S (K h) I),
```

or, after eta reduction,

```
S (S (K f) g) h,
```

where

```
S x y z = x z (y z)
K x y = x
```

Specifically in Haskell, thanks to @melpomene for pointing this out, the role of `S` is played by `ap`, and that of `K` by `const`. Therefore we can write

```
ap (ap (const f) g) h
```

In fact we can further reduce:

```
ap (const f) g = f . g
```

So our function can be written as:

```
ap (f . g) h
```

If translated to Applicative style, we obtain:

```
f <$> g <*> h
```

Then this systematic approach can be applied to all lambda terms, and gives the point-free style. :)